# Detecting newline character on user's input (web2py)

Tags: python, html, forms, web2py

I have the following table:

```
db.define_table('comm',
                Field('post','reference post', readable=False, writable=False),
                Field('body','text', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                auth.signature
                )
```

and in a python function, the following code:

```
form=SQLFORM(db.comm).process()
```

I call that form in the returned view by the python function

```
{{=form}}
```

The problem is when the user inputs two or more paragraphs, it doesn't detect the newline character. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Use pre tag to display the content in which you want to detect newline character.

[`<pre>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre)

> The HTML pre element (or HTML Preformatted Text) represents
>   preformatted text. Text within this element is typically displayed in
>   a non-proportional ("monospace") font exactly as it is laid out in the
>   file. Whitespace inside this element is displayed as typed.

```
{{for post in comments:}}
    <pre>{{=post.body}}</pre>
{{pass}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are referring to the subsequent display of the user input in a view, you could use a `<pre>` tag: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp. However, you might need some CSS to get the font/styling you like (by default, the browser will use alternative styling with a fixed-width font).

You could also replace the newlines with `<br>` tags:

```
{{=XML(record.body.replace('\n', '<br>'), sanitize=True, permitted_tags=['br/'])}}
```

Because the text now contains `<br>` HTML tags, it is necessary to wrap it in `XML()` to prevent web2py from escaping the HTML -- but you also want to sanitize the text and allow *only* `<br>` tags to prevent malicious code from being executed.