# Is there a web2py helper to convert a new line into a <br>?

Tags: web2py

I have text which includes new lines entered into a form. I want to display the text exactly as it was entered - with the new lines.

Just including the field value in the view of course does not do that - everything just appears on one line.

I have found the solution below and many others which usually involve replacing the '\n' with 'br' or using 'pre'. 'pre' works fine for me.
[Detecting newline character on user's input (web2py)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40824016/detecting-newline-character-on-users-input-web2py)

But this seems a bit clumsy. Is there A web2py helper that converts a string with newlines into a HTML string with 'br' or even putting each line into its own 'p' tag? It seems like it would be a common and rather helpful Helper.

Comment: No, there is no such built-in helper, but you can write one for yourself -- it's really just a one-liner.

Comment: Thanks Anthony. I might give that a go.